# Print formatted mathematical operations in R

Tags: r, math, printing, operation

I have in R a mathematical operation like this:

```
x = 5
y = (x / 5) * 2
```

and I want to print `y` to console or pdf file so it looks like:

(x / 5) * 2 like on the paper

[image]

Can I do this using R basic functions or some kind of library?

Comment: Can't you just print this: `y = x/5⋅2`

Comment: @GenisBillionaire, Yeah, it's not a problem but I would like to arrange it beautifully if it possible

Comment: It is not possible to write it manually but you can copy-paste it like `ˣ⁄₅`.

Answer (score 1):

@Yehor: you can use the power of RStudio and RMarkdown to combine text, code, and visualisations in output formats like pdf. Under the hood you need a bit more than *"some kind of library"*. But if you use RStudio as your R editor, the infrastructure (what you need) is actually in place already. RStudio will ask to have a few packages installed when you open a RMarkdown file for the first time, but do not worry about this.

In RStudio open a new RMarkdown file. During the opening dialogue you can (pre-)select an output type, e.g. pdf. Please note that you can change this later.
The example that opens gives you an idea of what you can do. The magic happens when you hit the *"knit-button"* in the top bar of the editor pane. R/RStudio will render the document and interpret code-chunks. These chunks can include "just" code, code to produce tables and/or graphics.

For math & formulae, RMarkdown supports 2 ways of presenting LATEX:

1. inline equation
2. equation mode

(I) inline equation - within single dollar signs $
You can include an inline equation anywhere in the text part of the Rmd document. For example:

```
    This is how I add a formula: $y := \frac{x}{5} * 2$ within a line using inline code.
```

(II) equation mode - statement within double dollar signs $$
For the equation mode use $$ and have this on a separate line in Rmd.

```
    $$y := \frac{x}{5} * 2$$
```

Knitting the Rmd in RStudio renders the document into a pdf (you can also export to html, MS Word or even Powerpoint).

For example:

[image]

is produced with this minimal Rmd:

[image]

If you want to combine this with the calculation, you would add a "code-chunk".
In RMarkdown you can include R-code inside 3 backticks, e.g. `{r} # R-stuff ...` 
Thus, the following code chunks performs the operation:

```
    x <- 5
    y <- (x/5) * 2
```

If you want to print the result "inline" in your text, you can add so-called inline code. This is done by having R-statement inside single backticks and a starting r, i.e. `r ...` within the text part of the Rmd. For example:

```
   My result is `r y` as inline code.
```

This will print: My result is 2 as inline code.
You could include more sophisticated R-statements as inline code by separating each statement with a semi-colon (~end of command line). However, I recommend to do the fluffy stuff in a code chunk and use the inline for simple statements. It is much easier on the eye and for debugging.